# TypeError: Class() takes no arguments when creating new instance of metaclass

Tags: python

I have the production code below (see section Code Under Test). I am also running the two automated tests against this code.

The first test (i.e. `test_database_connection`) runs successfully and sets up the database connection.

However, the second test (i.e. `test_call_stored_procedure`) fails with the error

```
    def __call__(cls, db_name: Databases, *args, autocommit: bool = False, **kwargs):
        """Load tables and caches in singleton."""
        if db_name not in cls._instances:
>           new_class = super(DBReflectionSingleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
E           TypeError: Database() takes no arguments
```

How come one test passes and the other fails, even though both are creating an instance of the Database class and passing the argument `autocommit=True`)? It doesn't make any sense to me.

**Code Under Test**

```
@functools.lru_cache()
def get_engine(database_name: Databases, autocommit=False) -> Engine:
    """Get an engine from a DB name.

    Cached to leverage the benefits.
    """
    if database_name is None:
        raise TypeError("database_name can't be None")

    db_params = get_app_params()
    conf_profiles = {}
    for database, db_param_keys in REQUIRED_DBS.items():
        conf_profiles[database] = DatabaseConfig(
            db_connection_template=db_params[db_param_keys.connection_string_key],
            db_password=db_params[db_param_keys.password_key],
            echo=False,
        )
    for database, db_param_keys in OPTIONAL_DBS.items():
        if (
            db_connection := db_params.get(db_param_keys.connection_string_key)
        ) is not None:
            conf_profiles[database] = DatabaseConfig(
                db_connection_template=db_connection,
                db_password=db_params[db_param_keys.password_key],
                echo=False,
            )

    conf: Optional[DatabaseConfig] = conf_profiles.get(database_name)
    if conf is None:
        raise TypeError(
            "Database does not exist.. check if you provided correct database name"
        )
    connection_string = (
        conf.connection_string + f"?autocommit={str(autocommit).lower()}"
    )
    engine = create_engine(connection_string, echo=conf.echo)
    return engine


class DBReflectionSingleton(type):
    """Singleton to load all tables from a database."""

    _instances: Dict = {}

    def __call__(cls, db_name: Databases, *args, autocommit: bool = False, **kwargs):
        """Load tables and caches in singleton."""
        if db_name not in cls._instances:
            new_class = super(DBReflectionSingleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            engine = get_engine(db_name, autocommit)
            meta = MetaData()
            meta.reflect(bind=engine, views=True)
            new_class.__dict__.update(meta.tables)
            new_class.engine = engine
            new_class.meta = meta
            cls._instances[db_name] = new_class
        return cls._instances[db_name]


class Database(
    metaclass=DBReflectionSingleton
):  # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
    """Cache the table reflected from given DB."""


def call_stored_procedure(
    databases: Databases,
    stored_proc: str,
    arguments: tuple,
    with_field_names: bool = False,
    autocommit: bool = False,
):
    """Call one instance of a stored procedure.

    Args:
        databases: database
        stored_proc: stored_proc_name
        with_field_names: Boolean Flag to return the data with field names.
        arguments: Stored proc parameters
    """
    database = Database(databases, autocommit)
    try:
        # we need to drop to DBAPI level to run stored procedures
        connection = database.engine.raw_connection()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.callproc(stored_proc, arguments)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        if with_field_names:
            column_names_list = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]
            result = list(dict(zip(column_names_list, row)) for row in result)
        cursor.close()
        connection.commit()
    finally:
        connection.close()
    return result
```

**Automated Tests**

```
def test_database_connection(aws_params_mock):
    """Verify that we can successfully call a stored procedure.

    This test will call a stored procedure using the default autocommit
    setting. The results will be checked to verify there is data returned.

    Args:
        aws_params_mock: Fixture that mocks the setup of required AWS DB params
    """
    result = Database(Databases.VOR, autocommit=True)
    assert isinstance(result, int)

def test_call_stored_procedure(aws_params_mock):
    """Verify that we can successfully call a stored procedure.

    This test will call a stored procedure using the default autocommit
    setting. The results will be checked to verify there is data returned.

    Args:
        aws_params_mock: Fixture that mocks the setup of required AWS DB params
    """
    result = call_stored_procedure(
        Databases.VOR,
        "usp_dms_get_da",
        ("AT", "2023-08-01", "Hourly", "EPEX"),
        autocommit=True,
    )
    result_length = len(result)
    print(f"test_call_stored_procedure: Length of results is {result_length}")
    assert result_length > 0
```